# How did C-3PO and R2-D2 get on Leia's ship?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Okay, so those of you who have seen it already, you know that the ending scene appears to take place just moments before Vader boards Leia's ship at the beginning of *A New Hope*.

But when the report came to the senator that rebels are on Scarif and Admiral Raddus is already on his way there, C-3PO and R2-D2 are seen on Yavin 4.

So did the last scene take place just before the beginning of *A New Hope*, and if so, how in the heck did the droids get on that ship?